# switching from https to http page in rails 3 results in infinite loop in Firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, firefox, mozilla, rails-ssl-requirement

I am using `bartt-ssl_requirement` for ssl implementation in `Rails 3.2.13` in `ngnix` server

```
gem 'bartt-ssl_requirement', '~>1.4.0', :require => 'ssl_requirement'
```

There are some pages which are to be https and some pages which are only http.

So I wrote in `application_controller.rb`

```
include SslRequirement
```

`ssl_required :new,create` in `sessions_controller.rb`

`ssl_required :show` in `settings_controller.rb`

When I switch from http page to https page, there is no problem.

But when I switch from https to any http, there is a infinite redirection loop in `Mozilla` .

I also tried with force-non-ssl for the http pages. But no change.

Can anyone help how to fix it either in Rails or ngnix server setting?

> Note: This problem occurs only in mozilla. But works fine in Chrome and Internet Explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code to redirect from http to https and vice versa

```
def ensure_proper_protocol
     if request.ssl? && !ssl_allowed_action?

       redirect_to "http://" + request.host + request.fullpath
     elsif !request.ssl? && ssl_allowed_action?

       redirect_to "https://" + request.host + request.fullpath 
     end
  end
```

And removed the `gem 'bartt-ssl_requirement'`

Still the problem did not go.

Then I simply changed in the `production.rb` in the `config/environments`

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

Its now working perfectly.